# Why set position relative when is not necessary

Tags: html, css, position

I see a lot of sites setting the `position: relative;` in block elements when they won't use position in inner elements. Is there any other reason to set the position relative?

Example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent__container">
    other elements here.
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent__container {
  position: relative;
  // etc
}
```

And the inner elements are not making any usage of position, sometimes i even see the .parent with `position: relative;` set.

This is very very common, i can point several sites that are setting the position without any necessaty (at least i think).

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to answer without a specific example, but `position: relative` lets you use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties, basically. Maybe they need it for a reason.

Comment: I can give you an example right now.. the stackover flow site is using it in the -container in the navbar, you can disable and see that is useless.

Comment: In SO's case they use it as there is a nav drop down, with class `topbar-dialog inbox-dialog dno`, that has `position: absolute` and is positioned based on that container ... so the normal reason is to be able to have a child use it when the child need to re-position itself, with absolute position, or re-position itself, as i.e. `top: 20px` won't work if it does not have a position, or if you use `z-index`, which only work on positioned elements

Comment: Hm, now it make senses... it's like Bootstrap.

Comment: There can also be a javascript somewhere, that at certain point add an element, which use absolute, and in those cases it also can appear it is set for no reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is basically 3 reasons why one set an element to `position: relative`

1. To re-position the element itself, i.e. `top: 20px`
2. To use `z-index` on that element. A side effect, if one does not set a `z-index`, it will still position itself on top of statically positioned elements.
3. Limit the scope of absolutely positioned child elements, so a child of the relatively positioned element can be absolutely positioned within that block.

---

Here is an old article that describes the difference between the most used position values:

- https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Perfect! That's what i learned, so, if a site has an element with position: relative set and there is no z-index, no top, left, right, bottom attributes and the children are not using any position, the position: relative is useless, right?

Comment: @FátimaAlves That would be correct, be aware though, there can be elements that could be added using script, which need the relative for any of the 3 given situations

Comment: Cool! Thanks very much @LGSon! <3

Answer (score 1):

Most websites these days use "relative" positioning to make their websites flexible and compatible with small-screen devices such as smart phones, and non-16x9-conforming devices. The original purpose of using relative over absolute positioning was to allow the programmer to allow the web-page to handle the positioning based on hierarchical order unless otherwise stated by the programmer.

**Edit:** Note that by defining "relative", it gives an element and its children a certain hierarchical order in the DOM model; it does not necessarily tell an element how to position itself (aka knowing to be aligned left or right), but rather creates a "box" or "container" in which an element and its children are given certain hierarchical order based on its nesting within HTML that the HTML document as a whole must conform to. In other words, "relative" defines the priority/hierarchy of an element in terms of its parents.

Conversely, if a programmer wanted to make certain elements staticly positioned, they would use "position: absolute;" to make that element static, relative to its parent. For example:

```html
    <div class="parentA">ParentA Text
      <div class="childA">
          All elements become positioned absolutely, requiring defined positions using margins, alginment and etc. Note that this may or may not be inherited depending on the browser and the code.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parentB">ParentB Text
      <div class="childB">
          All elements become positioned relatively, requiring no defined positions using margins, alginment and etc, unless desired. This makes the webpage very flexible (dynamic in the position of its elements).
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parentC">ParentC Text
      <div class="childC">
          All elements in and under childC become positioned absolutely relative to parentC, requiring defined positions using margins, alginment and etc.
          <div class="grandChildC">
          Grandchild
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <style>
    .parentA {
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .parentB {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    
    .parentC {
        margin: 60px;
    }
    .childC {
        position: absolute;
    }
    </style>
```

As seen in the above, since parentB is relative, it starts wherever parentA left off. Since parent A has no size and is defined as an absolute/static object, the two divs overlap. Conversely, since partentC is relative and childC is absolute, childC will move to wherever parentC is, however, its outline will remain static and on top of other elements, that is, static relative to the position of parentC.

I hope that this answers your question. If not, be more clearer in what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I think your answer is showing the behaviour of position absolute vs position relative. My question is related why manny sites set the position to relative if   is useless, like stackover flow navbar

Comment: As I mentioned at the beginning of my answer, it is to allow the flexibility of different sized screens by allowing the website to adjust element positions and flow accordingly without needing the programmer's instruction to do so and do it in an ordered manner. By defining "relative", it also give the element a sense of order, or heirarchy in which to organize itself on a screen. If you can't understand that, you're beyond help cause you can't get more explicit than that.

Comment: Saying _"relative" positioning to make their websites flexible and compatible with small-screen devices such as smart phones, and non-16x9-conforming devices_, that is completely wrong, it has nothing to do with that. Your whole answer gives the impression that when one set `position: relative` the whole site knows by itself what it should do in a certain situation, which of course it does not. I recommend you make some changes to get rid of those statements.

Comment: Can you give me an real example? I've never read and never heard of it.

Comment: Fatima, please see my updated answer as it may make more sense. 
And no, LGSon, my statement is not wrong. However, if I were to introduce "display:flex", then yes, it would make the statement confusing and incorrect. As mentioned in my edit, "relative" provides hierarchy among the elements, allowing them to order themselves accordingly without needing to be defined otherwise. Additionally, in a given situation, such as @media (min-width:300){}, this hierarchy still applies unless otherwise defined by the programmer. You're comment asserts there is no formatting other than position.

Comment: As for a real example, check out my personal website and look into the divs: [link](http://eecs.csuohio.edu/~secaldwe/). By using relative positioning, I can control what order the divs display in and by defining other properties, I can adjust their display however I want while still maintaining the original order (hierarchy) of the elements in the page.